# Custom Annotation attribute using ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried to implement custom annotataion using ASP.net MVC4. But the validation login implemented in custom javascript is throwing some error, like JQuery is null.
I have refered the link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC-3

Can anyone let me know is there anything I am missing here, when I implemented the same approach using MVC4?

Comment: I used the same code in the example said in the link. when i include the javascript file, the error pops up in the below line.                   --- --------jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add
  ---------------

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have made a reference to jQuery before any other script references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js")"></script>
```

Verify that the version is correct as well and that this file exists in the specified location. Usually this script reference is included in the Layout when you create a new ASP.NET MVC application but double check if this is the case for you and if it isn't add it.